# I configured Spring Aop + Transaction + Mybatis. However, Transaction not work

Tags: spring, transactions, aop, mybatis

I configured Spring Aop and Transaction. 
When I run the Project Test. the Transaction does not work and i got the log output as follows: "was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active"

When I run LoginServiceImpl.findMemberInfo() method, I got the Transaction registered Successfully. However, I run LoginServiceImpl.insertMember, the registration fails

root-context.xml as shown below:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package:"com.quapenus">
      <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
 </context:component-scan>
 <!-- transactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- txAdvice -->
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" />

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="find*" />
        <tx:method name="insert*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!-- Aspect -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="pointcut" expression="execution(* com.quapenus.*.service.*Impl.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="pointcut" advice-ref="txAdvice" />
</aop:config>
```

servlet-context as alown below:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

<bean id="jsonMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />

<bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
    <property name="contentType" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8" />
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jsonMapper" />
</bean>
```

LoginServiceImpl as shwon below:

```
@Service
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService  {
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private LoginDao loginDao;

@Override
public Member findMemberInfo(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException  {
    Member member = loginDao.findMemberInfo(username);

    if(member == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("아이디가 존재하지 않습니다.");
    }

    return member;
}

@Override
public List<GrantedAuthority> findRoles(String username) throws NotFoundException {
    List<GrantedAuthority> roles = loginDao.findRoles(username);

    if(roles.size() == 0){
        throw new NotFoundException("해당 역할이 없습니다.");
    }

    return roles;
}

@Override
public void insertMember(Member member) throws RollbackException {
    int result = loginDao.insertMember(member);

    if(result == 1){
        throw new RollbackException("Test Tx");
    }
}
}
```

LoginDao as shown below:

```
@Repository
public class LoginDao {
    @Autowired
    private SqlSession sqlSession;

    public Member findMemberInfo(String username) {
        return sqlSession.selectOne("com.quapenus.common.sql.LoginMapper.findMemberInfo", username);
    }

    public List<GrantedAuthority> findRoles(String username) {
        return sqlSession.selectList("com.quapenus.common.sql.LoginMapper.findRoles", username);
    }

    public int insertMember(Member member) {
        return sqlSession.insert("com.quapenus.common.sql.LoginMapper.insertMember", member);
    }
}
```

LoginServiceImpl.insertMember() Method log as shown below:

```
org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@77b976a0] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
17:13:01.100 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
```

LoginServiceImpl.findMemberInfo() Method log as shown below:

```
org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
17:58:07.052 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession
```

github repository: https://github.com/Sujin1135/Quapenus

Comment: Remove `mode="aspect"` and add `@Transactional` to your service.

Comment: I tried, It's the same

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do.... Do you want to use annotations or not? Judging from your configuration it can be either, however you aren't actually using annotations. Also add your dao.

Comment: In the configuration of your `DispatcherServlet` you have a `component-scan` tag which will lead to another (non-transactional) instance of the services and dao. You have an `include` filter but you aren't excluding everything else. Add `use-default-filters="false"` to that configuration.

Comment: I modified the post. Post add LoginDao source, context:component-scan of root-context, context:component-scan of servlet-context of servlet-context

Comment: As I already stated in my previous comment the error is the fact that you have 2 component scan annotations doing more or less the same leading to 2 instances of your service. I also explained you need to add `use-default-filters="false"` to the scan in your servlet.xml. Also you aren't posting everything here.

Comment: I try adding use-default-filters="false" for servlet-context.xml. However, It did not work. 

servlet-context.xml component-scan as shown below:

<context:component-scan base-package="com.quapenus">
            <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
        </context:component-scan>

Comment: incomprehensible, findMemberInfo Succeds and insertMember fails. but findMemberInfo and insertMember Method is LoginServiceImpl Class

Comment: There is no mention of said property in your xml file. Also the find doesn't insert anything that only does a find.